# How to untag Root Element in Indesign using Applescript

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I have Tried Following Code

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"

select text of XML element 1 of active document

set xmlelem to item 1 of associated XML elements of selection

untag xmlelem

end tell
```

I got an error

```
"Adobe InDesign CS5.5 got an error: This element cannot be deleted."
```

Is there any way to untag root element?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Even if you open up the `Structure` pane through the UI you can't delete or untag the root element (`View -> Structure -> Show Structure`).

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
    set doc to active document
    untag XML element 1 of doc
end tell
-- Error: This element cannot be deleted.
```

You *can* change the name of the root element though:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
    set doc to active document
    set name of markup tag of XML element 1 of doc to "NewRoot"
end tell
```